# How to remove a Required Field based on other field value

Tags: 7, forms

i have a form with two fields, FieldA (Select List) and FieldB (Select List, required field).

How to set the FieldB to optional when FieldA has certain value in order to pass the form validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mark the field B as not required if you have set the field as required using UI

```
if field B is not set as required then you can continue with the following code.<br/>
```

For none value in field B we can set custom form error using [form_set_error()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7);

```
     function hook_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form_id == 'abc') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'hook_abc_validate'
        }
        }

       function hook_abc_validate($form, $form_state) {

        if ($form['field_A']['und']['0']['value'] == 'your_value') {

        $form['field_B']['#required'] = 0;
        }
        else {
        $form['field_B']['#required'] = 1;


        }
    if ($form['field_B']['und']['0']['value'] == '_none') {
            form_set_error('field_B', 'field_B cannot be none');
            }
}
```

Comment: when the field is not set as required, there is a -none- value in the top of the list, so the form always get validated even thought user input nothing. am i missing something?

Comment: check the edited answer

Comment: so this line does nothing right? $form['field_B']['#required'] = 1; i still have to validate it by myself.

Comment: the line $form['field_B']['#required'] = 1 makes this field_B required and select list will have value '_none' for that we need to use form_set_error .Do you get this let me know?

Comment: by setting $form['field_B']['#required'] = 1 in the function hook_abc_validate has no effect to the field, neither validation nor the '*' mark. i understand the form_set_error part.

Comment: try true instead of 1 and false instead of 0 and then let me know

Comment: Also, there is no problem in setting custom error with 2 condition that the select list field B is not empty(1st condition) and (2nd condition) is value != '_none';

Comment: 1, true, TRUE is not working as well. :) i basically get what i wanted by using the form_set_error, i just want to make sure if the line $form['field_B']['#required'] = 1 is not required.

Comment: pls update your question if you wanted to prevent submit when select list field B is having value '_none' Then I would remove the code $form['field_B']['#required'] = 1 .So as per now it is not required. Pls upvote and correct if you found this answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try using the #states attribute: a structured array describing the different JavaScript states that can be applied to the element when certain conditions are met. Please read the extensive description of this feature at [drupal_process_states()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7)